# rolling-update is forced to delete old pod?

Tags: kubernetes

if rolling-update is forced to delete old pod, some responses about old pod will be interrupted.
Example:
Rc (myapp) define replicas 2 and contain 2 pods(myapp-mtlz8, myapp-an78c).
rolling-update rc (myapp).
When create a new pod(myapp-ed4988fb0b53ed961037a026068d1a3d-i8wvt) and start to delete a old pod(myapp-mtlz8). 
If old pod is being processed some requests, but the old pod is deleted. So some request don't complete about old pod.

Whether or not:
1. service don't proxy to old pod
2. Waiting to old pod completed all request
3. delete old pod

Answer (score 0):

I filed an issue to document the recommended practice. I put a sketch of the approach in the issue:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20473

- ensure the pods have a non-zero terminationGracePeriodSeconds set
- configure a readinessProbe on the main serving container of the pods
- handle SIGTERM in the application: fail the readinessProbe but continue * to handle normal requests and do not exit
- set maxUnavailable and/or maxSurge large enough to ensure enough serving instances in the Deployment API spec (available in 1.2)